# Como configurar CodeIgniter 4 para su ejecución y no eliminar la carpeta public y se ejecute

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Configurar CodeIgniter 4 para ejecutarse directamente sin necesidad de poner en la url la ruta hacia la carpeta public, ejemplo:

```
http://localhost/ci4login/
```

Y no tener que poner la ruta completa para que se ejecute.

```
http://localhost/ci4login/public/
```

Esto sin la necesidad de eliminar la carpeta public, o sacar de ella el archivo `index.php` y el archivo `.htaccess`  y así poder mantener toda la seguridad.

Utilizo CodeIgniter 3 y quiero migrar a CI4 y esta parte me frena ya que lo ideal es usar el framework como se diseño su uso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitarias agregar un archivo `.htaccess` adicional en la carpeta raiz de tu proyecto, **fuera** de la carpeta `public` (en tu caso ci4login) con lo siguiente:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /nombre-proyecto

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

<sup>* Cambiar `nombre-proyecto` por el nombre de tu carpeta raiz (ci4login)</sup>

Esto sobreescribirá cualquier url a la carpeta public de tu proyecto, necesitas tener activado `mod_rewrite` en la configuración del servidor apache.

Comment: Gracias mi util su repuesta, y con ella logre la solución a mi pregunta gracias de nuevo